# Cross platform SIMD library with similar API to the Accelerate Framework?

Tags: audio, simd

I'm using the Accelerate Framework to improve performance of an audio mixer, with very good results on iOS and OSX. I'm trying to achieve similar results on other platforms and cpu architectures - the usual suspects ( ARM android, x86 x64 PCs ).

I've investigated [Yeppp!](http://www.yeppp.info), which provides a nice C# wrapper, but which only covers very basic operations: no stride can be specified, no ramp functions for vector generation or processing neither ( vDSP_vrampmul is great… ), and no clipping neither.

Does anyone know of a cross platform SIMD library with a similar, audio DSP friendly API?

[ EDIT ]As Paul recommends, KissFFT seems perfect for frequency domain work, so what's left are simpler time domain operations.

Many thanks in advance,

Gregzo

Comment: Recommendations will most likely depend on which subset of functions you are using, and you may need more than one library, e.g. if you're doing frequency domain stuff with FFTs etc then you probably want something like KissFFT.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the KissFFT suggestion. For mixing, I'm mostly after vector multiply, add, copy, generate ramped, clip, interleave / de-interleave. Basic stuff, but not covered by Yeppp, alas.

Comment: OK - so mostly just basic time domain operations then ? I don't have any specific recommendations unfortunately, but you might want to add a sentence to your question just clarifying the kind of operations you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of promoting our own product, I'd suggest http://Superpowered.com, cross-platform (iOS & Android) pro audio SDK/library.

The Superpowered stereo mixer can be used to ‘split’ interleaved signals to non-interleaved, see here:

http://superpowered.com/pro-audio-sdk-update-android-arm-and-x86-64-bit-positioning/

Comment: Many thanks for this! Upvoted, but not accepted as I'd love to see more suggestions - your library seems absolutely excellent but geared towards iOS / Android and not desktop platforms.

Comment: Hi Gregzo -- so while our focus is on mobile, we do support desktop too - see http://superpowered.com/superpowered-audio-sdk-update-with-x86-64/ - thanks

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, looking forward to try it out.

Comment: @PatrickVlaskovits, I've a question, I want apply filters on a audio file, how do I save that new file (along with filters applied) ?

Comment: @hagile - can you send an email to patrick @ Superpowered and I will put it in our support queue. Thanks.